# How can non-US customers buy Kindle Active Content

Tags: kindle, tos

Kindle Active Content allows software to be purchased and used on the e-ink Kindles. It is however only available to US customers. Is there any way for foreign customers to buy these items?

I have heard suggestions such as changing your Amazon account postal address to a US address, though this might be in breach of their Terms of Service and I haven't done it as I don't want to risk my account. Is this a good idea?

Comment: Your safest bet in this situation is probably to contact Amazon and see if there is a legal way to buy the content for non-US customers.

Comment: I have tried before and they didn't even understand the problem!

Comment: Well that is disheartening.

Answer (score 1):

You got me curious, so I started digging through the terms of service. Keep in mind that I am not a lawyer, so anything I say is just my own personal interpretation of the terms.

---

After reading through who-knows-how-many documents, this is all I could come up with.

The [Kindle Store Terms](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201014950) state:

> "In addition, you may not **bypass**, modify, defeat, or circumvent security features that protect the Kindle Content." *(emphasis mine)*

This is a little vague, but using an address that isn't yours to access Kindle content could possibly be seen as "bypassing" security features.

Comment: The specific strategies I've seen have been to either use a friend's address or a rent-an-address company. That's not as suspect as making up an address, but it's still something I'm cautious about trying. Also I don't know if it even works.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon seems to have recently updated the options for account holders in the UK, at least. They now offer the option to change the account to one based on the US site, where payments are in USD. Services such as WhisperCast are also available. So potentially you'll be able to switch your account too (depending on whether Amazon offer you this option).

I was offered these options after selecting the change device country option. Here's the text I see on my current UK-based account (I have several accounts already set to the US option via the amazon.co.uk site):

```
You are currently linked to shop on Amazon.co.uk. Click <here> to learn more about other Amazon sites you are eligible to shop on based on your country of residence.
```

Clicking the link  causes the next text to appear on the page (nicely formatted):

```
Your Account > Manage Your Kindle > Manage Your Kindle Store
Your Kindle Store
To learn more about shopping for Kindle content and managing your Kindle account at another Amazon 
Kindle store, please select from the available Amazon Kindle stores for your country below:
Amazon.com/kindlestore 

Prefer to shop in US Kindle Store, make purchases in US Dollars, read reviews on Amazon.com?

Learn about transferring your Kindle account to Amazon.com


Amazon.co.uk/kindlestore 

Prefer to shop in UK Kindle Store, make purchases in Pounds Sterling, read reviews on Amazon.co.uk?

Your Kindle account is currently registered to Amazon.co.uk.
```

I've not investigated Active Content so I don't know whether it's available on converted accounts. Be aware that any remaining gift balance is not available to you once you convert the account.

Comment: I have a US account already (I'm in the opposite situation of Amazon prompting me to switch to an AUS account, which would also void my gift card balances.) So having an account on the US site alone isn't enough to be allowed to buy active content. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have someone who is physically in the US, log into your US amazon account and then change the residence address to a US address. You should then be able to buy kindle book even though you're not in the US. You can't change the address to a US address while you are abroad. Change of residence country/address to USA has to be done in the US itself. If you are changing to a US address while you are in Australia for example, Amazon will ask you to send proof of ID and utility bill to confirm that the change is authentic.

I have been going back and forth annually to the US as hubby is based there while I am here in my home country. As I have changed my address when I'm there, I have no trouble buying kindle books when I am based here in my home country.

Comment: Can you confirm that this allows you to buy Kindle Active Content?